# i want to show a html page view source but it redirect and show another site view source any one can help me how it done

Tags: html

i want to show a html page view source but it redirect and show another site view source any one can help me how it done
this is the url
https://www.stlouisco.com/rex/now8/MLB-v-Opening-Day-2020-on-tv0s01.html

Comment: The question is unclear and the title and the content are pretty much the same, provide some code that people can actually see and help you improve

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to inspect a page and view its source. A simple one is to right-click on the page and in the context menu, choose "View Page Source".

If right-clicking on the page doesn't work for you for some reason, try this:
In the address bar, add 'view-source' at the start of a webpage that you want to view the source for.

In your case, try this:

`view-source:https://mlb.streamsonline.live/`

Put it in the address bar at the top of the browser where you would normally put in the URL of the website.